# C# and powershell on Exchange 2010 - The term 'Group-Object' is not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, exchange-server

I have to list all databases in an exchange 2010 server with their mailboxes.

In Powershell I can run this,

```
Get-Mailbox -Server Exc2010 | Group-Object Database | Select-Object name,count


Name       Count
----       -----
DB01       16
DB04       3
DB02       2
DB03       5
```

However if I try the same in C#,

```
//Running cmdlets remotely
WSManConnectionInfo wsConnectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("https://" + ExchangeSite + "/powershell"),
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", getCredential());
wsConnectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
wsConnectionInfo.SkipCACheck = true;
wsConnectionInfo.SkipCNCheck = true;
wsConnectionInfo.SkipRevocationCheck = true;

rsRemoteRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(wsConnectionInfo);
rsRemoteRunspace.Open();

Collection<PSObject> Result = null;
Pipeline pipeLine = rsRemoteRunspace.CreatePipeline();

Command myCommand = new Command("Get-MailboxDatabase");
myCommand.Parameters.Add("Server", "Exc2010");
Command myCommand2 = new Command("Group-Object");
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("Property", "Database");

pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand2);
Result = pipeLine.Invoke();
```

I get,

```
The term 'Group-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

If I use Select-Object it works fine so I wonder why I'm getting that error using Group-Object.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

If I run it using Select-Object, it works fine:

```
Command myCommand = new Command("Get-MailboxDatabase");
myCommand.Parameters.Add("Server", "Exc2010");
Command myCommand2 = new Command("Select-Object");
myCommand2.Parameters.Add("Property", "Name");

pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand2);
Result = pipeLine.Invoke();

PSObject PSResult = Result.FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine("DB Name: " + PSResult.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
```

I get,

```
DB Name: DB01
```

Comment: Can you share more code?

Comment: Are you sure that you can use select-object?

Comment: @ShayLevy, please see my edition, it works using Select-Object.

Comment: Updated my answer, see why select-object is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running this in the remote management session provided by Exchange? If that's the case, you can only run cmdlets provided by Exchange and Group-Object is not one of them.

Comment: @David, is there a kind of supported command's list. Please see my last edition, I wonder why Select-Object is supported and Group-Object not.

Comment: Here is a place where you can find them: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124413.aspx

Comment: @m0dest0 you can get the list of available cmdlets with : Invoke-Command $session { Get-Command }. Surprisingly, Select-Object is in the list!

Answer (score 2):

@David is right. Only Exchange commands are available in the remote endpoint. You'd need to find another solution. Here's how I would do it in PowerShell:

```
$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://ex1/PowerShell/ -Authentication Basic -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-Command $s { Get-Mailbox } | Group-Object Database -NoElement
```

Notice that the grouping happens after the mailbox objects have arrived. I'm not s developer so I can't tell you how the code should look like in C#. I guess you need to create a local runspace and do the grouping in it.

UPDATE: You can find which cmdlets are available in the remote session with this:

```
Invoke-Command $session { Get-Command }
```

Beside the Exchange cmdlets, there are 5 PowerShell core cmdlets in the remote session: `Exit-PSSession`,`Get-FormatData`,`Measure-Object`,`Out-Deafult` and `Select-Object`. These cmdlets are a part of the restricted endpoint. Other than them no core cmdlets exists.

Answer (score 0):

I could not run group-object so I had to change the cmdlet in this way:

```
                Pipeline pipeLine = rsRemoteRunspace.CreatePipeline();
                Command myCommand = new Command("Get-Mailbox");
                myCommand.Parameters.Add("Server", Server);

                pipeLine.Commands.Clear();
                pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
                Mailboxes = pipeLine.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject obj in Mailboxes)
                {
                    if (mbCount.ContainsKey(obj.Members["Database"].Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        mbCount[obj.Members["Database"].Value.ToString()] += 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mbCount.Add(obj.Members["Database"].Value.ToString(), 1);
                    }
                }
                pipeLine = null;
            }

            foreach (String Database in mbCount.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Database : " + Database + " Mailboxes : " + mbCount[Database].ToString());
            }
```